# Trying to count rows per unique ID from JOINED table - MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have combined few tables with JOIN (all LEFT JOIN to be more specific).
Now I am trying to count the number of records from one of the tables (table - measures) per
unique Reference number from main table - referral on a condition.

One referral can have more than one measure, and each measure can have different Status (col status_calculation from measure table).
I am trying to create a column (Test) which will count all non-cancelled measures per referral.

With the code I currently have I get the total number of records where a measure is not with status "Cancelled", but I want to split this per referral.

Thanks,
Maria

Please see below the code I have so far:

```
SELECT r.reference, r.status, pcla.la_name, r.project_reference, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id))
FROM measure
WHERE status_calculation <> "Cancelled") AS "Test",
p.EPCR_GasProperty, DATE(r.created)
FROM referral r
LEFT JOIN postcode_la pcla ON r.postcode = pcla.postcode
LEFT JOIN measure m ON r.reference = m.reference
LEFT JOIN customer c ON r.reference = c.reference
LEFT JOIN survey s ON s.customer_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN property p ON p.id = s.property_id
AND DATE(r.created) > "2022-03-31"
AND m.completed IS NOT NULL
AND pcla.la_name = "Ealing" 
GROUP BY r.reference
ORDER BY r.reference
LIMIT 20;
```

this is the result I am getting:

[result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ5jT.png)

Hopefully someone can advise what is it that I am missing..

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include only all references that belong

like

```
SELECT r.reference, r.status, pcla.la_name, r.project_reference, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(m1.id))
FROM measure m1
WHERE m1.status_calculation <> "Cancelled"
and m1.reference = r.reference) AS "Test",
p.EPCR_GasProperty, DATE(r.created)
FROM referral r
LEFT JOIN postcode_la pcla ON r.postcode = pcla.postcode
LEFT JOIN measure m ON r.reference = m.reference
LEFT JOIN customer c ON r.reference = c.reference
LEFT JOIN survey s ON s.customer_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN property p ON p.id = s.property_id
AND DATE(r.created) > "2022-03-31"
AND m.completed IS NOT NULL
AND pcla.la_name = "Ealing" 
GROUP BY r.reference
ORDER BY r.reference
LIMIT 20;
```